# Token Based Authentication - DbContext Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add refresh tokens to my existing Web API project. The initial token authentication is based on the example [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

This works perfectly as expected

When trying to continue on with adding Refresh Tokens using the follow up tutorial [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/).

> As soon as I get to to the section to add two `DbSets` to the existing
>   `AuthContext` `IdentityDbContext` authentication stops working
>   (`DefaultConnection` is the correct connection string in web.config).

```
 public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AuthContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}
```

Working back though the code the `UserManager.FindAsyn`c method is returning null for the user, even though the login details are exactly as before.

I have checked the `UserManger` is using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1 and the corresponding tables are in the database.

> As soon as I remove the two DbSets the authentication works again, and
>   trying the sample project included on the tutorials it works fine

Can anyone suggest why this happens and how I could fix it?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: In addition to adding the two new entites have you updated your database?

Comment: Yes, both Clients and RefreshTokens tables are in the database

Comment: Did you update the database through EF or manually? It sounds like your model and database are out of sync hence why removing the entites from your database context fixes the issue.

Comment: The tables were created though EF Migrations so should match the entities?

Comment: For reference the project also has a ApplicationDbContext that was created with the project for MVC auth. Not sure if that would create problems?